# Native and Handle pointers in C++ CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I was wondering if there is any way a native pointer can point to a Managed Heap ? I know this would be a dangerous thing to do, given heap compaction and GC cycles changing object address but is it still possible ? An example would be appreciated.

Also, is it true that a Handle (^) cannot point to native heap at all ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're trying to do, but in all my applications I found that doing something like this was unnecessary. I was able to solve all my problems having pointers to the unmanaged heap in my managed classes and having handles to the managed heap in my unmanaged classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's supported but the object that's pointed-to needs to be *pinned*.  You do so with .NET's GCHandle::Alloc() or by using the C++/CLI `pin_ptr<>` class.  Pinning objects for a long time is Bad, they give the garbage collector a hard time since it needs to work around the rock in the road.  Pinning is very common when calling native code.

A tracking reference (hat) to a block in the native heap makes no sense, they only track objects in the garbage collected heap.